# Problema al insertar datos en tabla hechos SSIS ETL

Tags: ssis, etl

estoy haciendo un ETL para extraer datos de la base de datos de microsoft AdventureWorks2022 a modo de aprendizaje y adaptarlos a un modelo estrella. Son varias cosas así que daré todo el contexto

Este es el diseño del modelo estrella

[image: Modela Estrella]

la creacion del modelo estrella es con la siguiente Query (en Sql server microsoft)

```
use estrella;


drop table DimTiempo;
drop table DimLugar;
drop table DimProducto;
drop table HechosVentas;

delete from HechosVentas;
delete from DimLugar;
delete from DimProducto;
delete from DimTiempo;

DROP SEQUENCE seq_dim_fecha_id;
DROP SEQUENCE seq_dim_lugar_id;
DROP SEQUENCE seq_dim_producto_id;

ALTER SEQUENCE seq_dim_fecha_id RESTART WITH 1;
ALTER SEQUENCE seq_dim_lugar_id RESTART WITH 1;
ALTER SEQUENCE seq_dim_producto_id RESTART WITH 1;

select * from HechosVentas;
select * from DimLugar
select * from DimProducto
select * from DimTiempo


CREATE TABLE [DimTiempo] (
    dim_fecha_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    anio INT,
    mes INT
);


CREATE TABLE [DimLugar] (
    dim_lugar_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    territory_id INT,
    territory VARCHAR(255)
);


CREATE TABLE [DimProducto] (
    dim_producto_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    product_id INT,
    product_name VARCHAR(255)
);


CREATE SEQUENCE seq_dim_fecha_id START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_dim_lugar_id START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_dim_producto_id START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE TABLE [HechosVentas] (
    cod_hechosventas INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    dim_fecha_id INT DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR seq_dim_fecha_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [DimTiempo](dim_fecha_id),
    dim_lugar_id INT DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR seq_dim_lugar_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [DimLugar](dim_lugar_id),
    dim_producto_id INT DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR seq_dim_producto_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [DimProducto](dim_producto_id),
    ventas_actuales_neto DECIMAL(18, 2),
    ventas_actuales_bruto DECIMAL(18, 2),
    transporte VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Dentro de VS SSIS

[image: Proceso ETL SSIS]

Dentro del Script Sql antes de entrar al flujo de datos tiene el siguiente comando sql:
[image: limpiar tabla]

El proceso ETL en cuestión, los campos (de todas las tablas):

```
dim_fecha_id
cod_hechosventas
dim_lugar_id
dim_producto_id
```

seguí la idea de hacerlos autoincrementales, una observación acá es que en la tabla HechosVentas, especificamente dim_fecha_id y dim_lugar y dim_producto_id no uso identity(1,1), si no secuencias.

sin embargo, al ejecutar el proceso ETL se puede evidenciar lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Inserta datos en casi todas las tablas, excepto en HechosVentas, cosa que desconozco ya que es de mis primeros ETL y he buscado por internet pero no comprendo bien cómo podría solucionarlo.

el mensaje de error que me arroja (algo largo) es:

```
Iniciando el paquete SSIS 'C:\Users\algodon\source\repos\ETL modelo estrelaa ev2\ETL modelo estrelaa ev2\Package.dtsx'.
Información: 0x4004300A en Flujo de datos, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Información: 0x4004300A en Flujo de datos, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Advertencia: 0x80049304 en Flujo de datos, SSIS.Pipeline: Warning: Could not open global shared memory to communicate with performance DLL; data flow performance counters are not available.  To resolve, run this package as an administrator, or on the system's console.
Advertencia: 0x80047076 en Flujo de datos, SSIS.Pipeline: The output column "DueDate" (115) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (113) and component "Extraer campos necesarios" (102) is not subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output column can increase Data Flow task performance.
Advertencia: 0x80047076 en Flujo de datos, SSIS.Pipeline: The output column "SalesTerritoryID" (121) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (113) and component "Extraer campos necesarios" (102) is not subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output column can increase Data Flow task performance.
Información: 0x40043006 en Flujo de datos, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Información: 0x40043007 en Flujo de datos, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
Información: 0x4004300C en Flujo de datos, SSIS.Pipeline: Execute phase is beginning.
Error: 0xC0202009 en Flujo de datos, Datos en HechosVentas [68]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__HechosVen__dim_f__43D61337". The conflict occurred in database "estrella", table "dbo.DimTiempo", column 'dim_fecha_id'.".
Error: 0xC0209029 en Flujo de datos, Datos en HechosVentas [68]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Datos en HechosVentas.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "Datos en HechosVentas.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Error: 0xC0047022 en Flujo de datos, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Datos en HechosVentas" (68) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (81). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Error: 0xC02020C4 en Flujo de datos, Extraer campos necesarios [102]: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
Error: 0xC0047038 en Flujo de datos, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Extraer campos necesarios returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Información: 0x40043008 en Flujo de datos, SSIS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning.
Información: 0x4004300B en Flujo de datos, SSIS.Pipeline: "Datos en DimLugar" wrote 9916 rows.
Información: 0x4004300B en Flujo de datos, SSIS.Pipeline: "Datos en DimProductos" wrote 9916 rows.
Información: 0x4004300B en Flujo de datos, SSIS.Pipeline: "Datos en DimTiempo" wrote 9916 rows.
Información: 0x4004300B en Flujo de datos, SSIS.Pipeline: "Datos en HechosVentas" wrote 9916 rows.
Información: 0x40043009 en Flujo de datos, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
Error de la tarea: Flujo de datos
Advertencia: 0x80019002 en Package: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (5) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
Paquete SSIS 'C:\Users\algodon\source\repos\ETL modelo estrelaa ev2\ETL modelo estrelaa ev2\Package.dtsx' finalizado: Error.
El programa '[13900] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' terminó con código 0 (0x0)
```

Creo que es necesario mostrar como tengo orquestado OLE DB SOURCE y OLE DB DESTINATION:

OLEDB SOURCE:

[image: oledb source]

[image: OLE DB SOURCE COLUMNS]

Y para OLE DB DESTINATION

[image: OLE DB DESTINATION]

[image: OLE DB DESTINATION COLUMNS]

como se ve, he omitido insertar datos en los campos dim de HechosVentas ya que, según mi lógica utilizando secuencias podemos generarlos automaticamente.

La conexión a la base de datos e inserción de datos en las tablas de dimensiones las realiza correctamente, ya que solo tienen un autoincremental identity(1,1), cosa que no genera problema.

Sin más que decir, si necesitan más información o ayudarme a resolver este error, se los agradecería un montón.

Answer (score 0):

Al final era el orden de inserción de los datos en las tablas, ya que daba problemas con las claves foraneas... Solución? insertar primero en las tablas adyacentes a la de hechos
[image: nuevo flujo de control]

Dentro de Rellena modelo estrella

[image: flujo de datos]

Dentro de RellanaHechosVentas

[image: hechosVentas]

[image: OLE DB DESTINATION]

[image: mapping]